# MATLAB : Adding Title to a matrix

Tags: matlab

The data

```
  x=[33 44 29; 16 25 45; 33 19 54; 22 21 49; 11 24 56];
```

contains the sale of a product for 5 days in three different shops. So the column denote shop 1,2 & 3 AND the rows denotes Monday to Friday  .

Now i computed the summary statistics for each day.

```
 meanday=mean(x');
 medianday=median(x');
 minday=min(x');
 maxday=max(x');
 varianceday=var(x');
 summaryday=[meanday;medianday;minday;maxday;varianceday];
```

Now i want to add title like this :

```
 summaryday =

                Mean       Median   Minimum   Maximum    variance
  Monday        32.3333   28.6667   35.3333   27.6667   30.3333
  Tuesday       33.0000   25.0000   33.0000   22.0000   24.0000
  Wednesday     20.0000   16.0000   19.0000   21.0000   11.0000
  Thursday      44.0000   45.0000   54.0000   40.0000   56.0000
   Friday       144.3333  220.3333  310.3333  114.3333  536.3333
```

How can  i add the title ?

Comment: You might find [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/09/10/introduction-to-the-new-matlab-data-types-in-r2013b/) interesting. Only available from R2013b though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have R2013b or later, the nicest solution is to write a small class around an ordinary matrix, that just implements the constructor and the `disp` function.

Here's an example of what that would look like:

```
>> W = WeeklyStatistics(rand(7,5), 'Mean', 'Median', 'Minimum', 'Maximum', 'Variance')

W = 
                            Mean          Median         Minimum         Maximum        Variance
          Monday        0.228977        0.442678        0.084436        0.263803        0.853031
         Tuesday        0.913337        0.106653        0.399783        0.145539        0.622055
       Wednesday        0.152378        0.961898        0.259870        0.136069        0.350952
        Thursday        0.825817        0.004634        0.800068        0.869292        0.513250
          Friday        0.538342        0.774910        0.431414        0.579705        0.401808
        Saturday        0.996135        0.817303        0.910648        0.549860        0.075967
          Sunday        0.078176        0.868695        0.181847        0.144955        0.239916

>>
```

Here's the class I used for that:

```
classdef WeeklyStatistics < double

    properties
        columnTitles

        weekDays = {
            'Monday'
            'Tuesday'
            'Wednesday'
            'Thursday'
            'Friday'
            'Saturday'
            'Sunday'
        };

    end

    methods
        function obj = WeeklyStatistics(M, varargin)
            obj = obj@double(M);

            %// Just copy the data
            obj.columnTitles = varargin;

            %// NOTE: very basic checks (you might want to think a bit more
            %// about these
            if ~all(cellfun('isclass', obj.columnTitles, 'char'))
                error('WeeklyStatistics:invalid_column_titles',...
                    'Invalid column title format. All column titles should be given as strings.');
            end

            if size(obj,2) ~= numel(obj.columnTitles)
                error('WeeklyStatistics:dimension_mismatch',...
                    'Number of columns in data disagrees with number of column titles.');
            end

            if size(obj,1) > numel(obj.weekDays)
                error('WeeklyStatistics:dimension_mismatch',...
                    'Number of rows in data exceeds number of days in a week.');
            end

        end

        %// These are needed to make the matrix behave like an ordinary matrix       
        function R = subsref(obj,varargin)
            R = subsref(double(obj), varargin{:}); end        
        function R = subsasgn(obj,varargin)
            R = WeeklyStatistics(subsasgn(double(obj), varargin{:}), obj.columnTitles{:}); end

        %// Show the matrix      
        function disp(obj)

            %// Print column titles
            fprintf(1,repmat(' ',1,16));
            fprintf(1,'%16s', obj.columnTitles{:});
            fprintf(1,'\n');

            %// Print data for all weekdays            
            dobj = double(obj);            
            for ii = 1:size(dobj,1)
                fprintf(1, '%16s', obj.weekDays{ii});
                fprintf(1,'%16f',dobj(ii,:));
                fprintf(1,'\n');
            end
            fprintf(1,'\n');

            %// NOTE: proper disp() implementations check the current setting
            %// of format() and adjust spacing and formatting accordingly

        end        
    end    
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For Matlab versions earlier than 2013b you could use cell array.

Comment: What abou 2013b? Newer version not keeping up the support or what!?#

Comment: Now I see, your reply was in addition to Rody Oldenhuis as there are new satatypes in R2013b :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the statistics toolbox a "[dataset](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html)" can have titles and descriptions of the columns. (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837802/headers-in-dataset-matlab))